# Can those problematic elements be changed as zeros with a loop in order to keep the sustainability?

Tags: python, pandas, list, algorithm, data-structures

I have a dataframe which contain 'date' as index and 'Sample Value' feature. This dataframe shows sample results on these dates. However, some of the sample results are repeating since the samples could not be taken on the date. For instance, first sample was taken on `2019-08-17 07:30:00`. Since the second sample could not be taken on `2019-08-17 08:00:00`, it shows the result as same as the previous one. I need to change these values with zeros in order to clean the data but I could not figure out how to do it. Is there any possible way to make this happen? I will put the desired outcome as `dataframe_desired`

```
dataframe =     
date                    Sample Result
2019-08-17 07:30:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 08:00:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 08:30:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 09:00:00     553.099976
2019-08-17 09:30:00     555.346976
2019-08-17 10:00:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 10:30:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 11:00:00     546.750000
2019-08-17 11:30:00     546.750000
```

```
dataframe_desired = 

date                    Sample Result
2019-08-17 07:30:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 08:00:00     0.000000
2019-08-17 08:30:00     0.000000
2019-08-17 09:00:00     553.099976
2019-08-17 09:30:00     555.346976
2019-08-17 10:00:00     548.700012
2019-08-17 10:30:00     0.000000
2019-08-17 11:00:00     546.750000
2019-08-17 11:30:00     0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job...

```
dataframe["Dup Result"] = dataframe["Sample Result"].duplicated(keep='first')
dataframe["Clean Result"] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: 0.0 if row["Dup Result"] else row["Sample Result"], axis=1)
dataframe = dataframe.drop("Dup Result", axis=1)
```

Comment: This code skips a scenario. Lets examine 09:00, 09:30 and 10:00 example. When you run this code, 09:30 sample will be shown as 0. However, it needs to be 553.346976. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understoof your question correctly, you're trying to set values that are equal to the previous to zero. This can be done by with the diff method:

```
df.loc[df.diff().squeeze()==0]=0
```

Here diff returns a dataframe with diff_i,j = df_i,j -  df_i-1,j. Squeezez is used to cast the single column dataframe to a serie so when can pass it as an index to loc. We then set the value 0 where the differences were 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff`:

```
df.loc[df['Sample Result'].diff().eq(0), 'Sample Result'] = 0
```

Comment: Question: Between 2 dates, the value can't be really the same? Why do you use 0 and not `NaN` for missing values?

Comment: With this method, you have to ensure your index is complete with no missing date